# A length macro in display math and inline math and \text command

Tags: math-mode

I want a length macro, named `\mymathspace`, which is changeable in inline math (including `\text` command) and display math. For example,

```
Text mode $inline\ math\vert\mymathspace\vert{}inline\ math$
```

get a space 6mu between the `\vert`s; and

```
\[display\ math\vert\mymathspace\vert{}display\ math\]
```

get a space 18mu between the `\vert`s; while

```
\[display\ math\text{Text mode $math\ in\ text\ command
\vert\mymathspace\vert$}display\ math\]
```

get a space 6mu between the `\vert`s. But I can't obtain this by `\if@display` and `\ifmmode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ifinner` is what you want:

```
\newcommand*\mymathspace{%
    \mskip\ifinner6\else18\fi mu
}
```